# ionic splashscreen delay not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I am using following config.xml

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="15000"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
```

and in app.js (ionic ready function):

```
var hideSplashscreen = function() {
    if (navigator && navigator.splashscreen) {
      navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }
  };
  $timeout(hideSplashscreen, 5000);
```

Splashcreen delay not working, app runs and quickly hide splash screen. I want it to be displayed for 3-5 seconds but it only displays for 1 second and redirect to state.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/start');

$stateProvider
  .state('start', {
    url: '/start'
  });
```

Please help/guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increased the delay and it worked:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
```

and in app.js

```
var hideSplashscreen = function() {
    if (navigator && navigator.splashscreen) {
      navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }
  };
  $timeout(hideSplashscreen, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get refrence with this link.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen